# Can't connect to local Minecraft server using cloudflare argo tunnels

Tags: tunnel, cloudflare

I'm trying to create a local Minecraft server and want people who are not in my home-network to be able to connect to the server. So I looked into it and found out about Cloudflare argo tunnels. I followed [their documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/install-and-setup/tunnel-guide) but it didn't work. I think everything is working up until running the tunnel. When I run "cloudflared tunnel run minecraft" the command just doesn't end (gets stuck in a loop or something) and I'm not able to connect to the server via the subdomain I assigned. The url in my config.yaml file in the .cloudflared directory is http://localhost:25565.

Is that the wrong url or do I have to wait for the dns for propagate?

Also once I run a tunnel how do I stop it? Do I have to shut down my computer or how does that work?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft runs on TCP/UDP protocols. You are trying to access your server using an http protocol.

Cloudflared is optimized for serving website content. You probably can get this working but the latency will be horrible. Use something like CloudFlare spectrum.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).